# Deserialising JSON String with JSON object serialised in the string

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialise a JSON string

```
string filter = @"[{""property"":""Student_PK"",""value"":""1""}]";
```

My first step was to

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(filter)
```

which didn't work. However, I added a class to deserialise the object.

```
public class filterObject
{
    [JsonProperty("property")]
    string property {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    Object value { get; set; }
}
```

Running the following also did not work

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<filterObject>(filter)
```

In this scenario, I do not have control over the filter string since this is generated by Sencha.

How else can I deserialise this JSON string as well as accommodating multiple JSON objects(property value combination) returned in a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root is an array of Objects and not an object.

Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(filter)`

Or with the second approach it should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<filterObject[]>(filter)`

Comment: I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(filter)`
I then added a `.ToDictionary(c => c["property"], c =>  c["value"])` to convert this back into a `Dictionary<string, string`

Answer (score 1):

Data in the format of JSON array, So serialize Json with the List of the Object class, Try this one,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<filterObject>>(filter);
```

Comment: Using this I could not retrieve the value of the keys property and value.